# Trim string until specified character and also trim suffix

Tags: php, string, explode, trim, substr

I don't know if this is possible using trim, substr or explode. 
What I have is a echo that prints this type of a string (it's actually a breadcrumb)

```
Choose > Apples > Green > Wholesale > 5KG boxes
```

Is it possible to chop the string so it prints only

```
Apples > Green
```

The structure of the breadcrumbs is fixed, so I will always want to chop the first part (`Choose >`) and the last two parts (`> Wholesale > 5KG boxes`) so I need to chop everything until the first "`>`" character and everything after the 3rd "`>`" character including the characters.

Comment: Explode the string on `>`, then contenate the elements you want from the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by exploding the string into an array. After that you just print the two items you need.

```
$string = 'Choose > Apples > Green > Wholesale > 5KG boxes';
$stringParts = explode(' > ', $string);
$newString = $stringParts[1].' &gt; '.$stringParts[2];
```

Comment: Hmm,
For some reason I get " Undefined offset: " errors if I feed my strings wich contain characters like below
`Apples > Package (E030) [AX/1982 - BX/1992] > 5KG (1596grams/100pcs) [AX/1987 - BX/1991] (red) boxed > Expire date > 10.16.2018`

I made a function using the above code

Comment: This is how it works for me 
`$string = 'Choose > Apples > Green > Wholesale > 5KG boxes';
$stringParts = explode(' &gt; ', $string);
$newString = $stringParts[1].' &gt; '.$stringParts[2];`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

```
$string = "Choose > Apples > Green > Wholesale > 5KG boxes";
echo preg_replace('~^[^>]*>\s*|\s*(?:>[^>]*){2}$~', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
Apples > Green
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out the issue, I had to change 
`$stringParts = explode(' > ', $string);` to
`$stringParts = explode(' &gt; ', $string);` and now it works.

How can I use `&gt;` in preg_replace ? I have to escape it correct ? Right now it doesn't do nothing, most likely I have to use the alternative `&gt;`

Comment: yep, `$` is a special character in regex. You must need to escape that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$separator = ' > ';
$string = "Choose > Apples > Green > Wholesale > 5KG boxes";
//explode your string, but keep in mind someone could use > in the content
$parts = explode($separator, $string);

//unset the first
array_shift($parts);
array_pop($parts); //unset the last one
array_pop($parts); //unset the second last

//combine them back thogether
$output = implode($separator, $parts);
```